# Should feedback in First Answers queue include a "Duplicate" option?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, first-answers

I recently [reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/29668770) [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68940605/8712097) and found it to be an accurate and useful answer except for the fact that it is near duplicate of [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68450743/8712097) to the same question.

I left a comment, but the only options for feedback are "Answer is unclear" and "Answer needs supporting information":

[image: First Answers Feedback Options]

Should "Answer is a duplicate" also be an option? Or is SO not concerned about duplicate answers?

Comment: Interesting question. I'd assume that duplicate answer are mostly unsalvageable, flag them as NAA.

Comment: @yivi: It's not a duplicate. Sharing feedback is not the same as flagging a question. There could at least be a discussion here if duplicate answers should only be flagged or if there should be a feedback options without flagging

Comment: AFAIK, [duplicate answers should be flagged as "in need of moderator intervention"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292391/348149).